# Skip-Erase when flashing data on embedded device

Tags: embedded, iar, flashing

I'm trying to flash different data-structures **within the same block** on my embedded device.
The data-structures are serial-number, test-result, configuration-data and other production-data, each in a separate HEX file, created at a different stage of production. It is not possible to append the HEX files and flash them in a single operation.
It's a Toshiba TMPM470 CPU, connected via miniJLINK, and IAR 7.40 IDE.
I tried using the IDE, the internal bootloader via the Toshiba FLASH-Programmer utility, J-Flash/J-Flash Lite, J-Link Commander... HELP!!!

**So my question is: is there a tool that writes binary data to the Toshiba CPU (to an 0xFF area, of coarse) without erasing the whole block?**
Thanks

Comment: The memory technology itself relies on an erase step, so it is not possible to do things the way you want.  Now, you could read the existing data, append it to your .hex file, then write the new resulting hex file...  But it may be easier for you just to use separate pages for the info.

Comment: Is it possible to collect the different HEX files, merge them and flash the merged file at the end of production? Otherwise, do a series of read-modify-write operations as suggested by Ross

Comment: Actually - it is possible to do so, and done so. The ST-Link-Utility (for STM32 devices) has the SKE (Skip Erase Flash) flag, though I don't know how it is implemented internally, but a user-bootloader (which updates app's and does the 'jump' to the app) can do whatever it wants with its flash-driver, such as not erase a block before writing to it...

Comment: Your question is not answerable at the moment, because there isn't any question asked. Please [edit] your question to ask about one small very specific problem.

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: Indeed you have, but unfortunately asking for specific tools is off topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's possible with the SEGGER J-Flash utility.
I just had to fight the configuration a bit and then **Target->Manual Programming->Program** simply did it.